# TypeError: descriptor 'remove' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Tags: python

Deseo hacer un programa que lea si una frase es palíndromo o no.

Ya vi lo que sube la gente sobre palíndromos en python pero quise hacerlo un poco diferente, sin embargo ya me quedé atorada con el problema porque se queda corto. Sólo necesito remover los espacios en blanco, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> TypeError: descriptor 'remove' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
def palindromo():
    p=str(input("Introduce una frase: "))
    p_list=list(p)
    p_list_rev=list(reversed(p))
    
    for element in p_list:
        list.remove(' ',)
    
    print(p_list)
    print(p_list_rev)
   
    if p_list==p_list_rev:
        print("Es un palindromo")
    else:
        print("No es un palindromo")
     
palindromo()
```

Comment: El método `remove` es específico de las listas, además estas usando una palabra reservada (que ni siquiera la haz definido)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dije en mi comentario el error es que el método `remove` es propio de las listas y aparte de que comentes el error de hacer `list.remove` donde `list` no está definido y es una palabra reservada. No necesitas hacer ningún ciclo y con una simple comprensión de lista puedes desacerté de los espacios.

```py
def palindromo():
    p = input("Introduce una frase: ").lower() #esto ya devuelve un string

    p_list = [letra for letra in p if letra!=" "]
    p_list_rev = [letra for letra in reversed(p) if letra!=" "]

    if p_list==p_list_rev:
        print("Es un palindromo")
    else:
        print("No es un palindromo")
```

La comprensión de lista no es nada más que un ciclo `for` *reducido*, en la cual se hacen operaciones concretas y *simples*, la sintaxis es:

```
[<operación> for <variable> in <iterable> <condición>]
```

Lo que quiere decir que se hará una operación para cada variable, y en caso de haber una condición solo se almacenará el valor si dicha condición se cumple. Puedes hacerlo con un ciclo `for` normal si no te resulta muy cómod.

```py
def palindromo():
    p = input("Introduce una frase: ").lower()

    p_list = []
    for letra in p: #recorremos la variable p
        if letra!=" ": #comprobamos que no este vacio
            p_list.append(letra) #agregamos a la lista

    p_list_rev = []
    for letra in reversed(p): #recorremos la lista invertida
        if letra!=" ": #comprobamos que no sea vacio
            p_list_rev.append(letra) #agregamos
```

Como habrás notado en la comprensión de lista no hay un `append` en donde iría la operación y esto es por que por defecto ya se van agregando. La comprensiones de lista son muy útiles y más rápidas que los ciclo `for` convencionales.

Comment: oooh muchas gracias, lo único que no me quedó claro fue la comprensión de lista, por todo lo demás super bien, porque se respetó más o menos lo que quería

Comment: ok, ahora edito la respuesta añadiendo la explicación de la comprensión de lista

Comment: super!!! gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario hacer `str(input("..."))`, pues `input(...)` devuelve un string.

No necesitas convertir el string a lista; los string y listas son bastante parecidos en Python.

Para invertir el string `p` basta con un rebanado:

```
p_invertido = p[::-1]
```

En el rebanado se omitió el indice de inicio y de fin, por lo que cubre todo el string. La gracia está en el `-1` al final, que le dice como avanzar por los caracteres. El valor `-1` hace que el string se recorra del final al principio.

Entonces, para comprobar si un string `p` es palindromo, basta con revisar la condición.

```
p == p[::-1]
```

En resumen, el código final es:

```
def palindromo(p):
    return p == p[::-1]

p = input("Introduce una frase: ").
print(len(p))
if palindromo(p):
    print("Es un palindromo")
else:
    print("No es un palindromo")
```

#### Demo

También separamos la entrada/salida del procesamiento. Esto da flexibilidad a la hora de reutilizar el código. Por ejemplo, puedo probar la función sin tener que ingresar los textos cada vez:

```
def palindromo(p):
    return p == p[::-1]

tests = [
    "",
    "a",
    "abba",
    "padre",
    "ab ba"
]
for test in tests:
    if palindromo(test):
        print(test, "es palindromo")
    else:
        print(test, "no es palindromo")
```

produce:

```
 es palindromo
a es palindromo
abba es palindromo
padre no es palindromo
ab ba es palindromo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: mil gracias!!! me quedó super claro